# SpringBoot missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I keep getting this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

This is the target in my run configuration.

```
package mystuff;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "mystuff")
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

And this is MyApp.class:

```
package mystuff;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyApp {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And this is my Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit", "junit", "4.12")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Both MyApp.java and Runner.java are in the same package, "mystuff". I searched around here on Stackoverflow, but my configuration appears to be correct.

Comment: You ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe try to to

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "mystuff")
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Runner.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Runner` class, replace

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class).run(args);
```

with

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET).run(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

.build() method should be called before .run()

please try below code

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class).build().run(args);
```